# Laravel excel Check image name with space not working

Tags: php, excel, laravel, laravel-excel

Excuse me, 
I use laravel excel using blade and there are images on the cells..
I do file exist checking.. Like this:

```
        <?php if (file_exists('assets/images/upload/' . $row->photo)) { ?>
            <td width="50" margin="0"><img src="assets/images/upload/{{$row->photo}}" width="50"/></td>
        <?php } else { ?>
            <td></td>
        <?php } ?>
```

I try debug that file_exist() method and return true..
But When I try to generate that report, Laravel excel generating this error:

```
File assets/images/upload/my%20working%20directory.jpg not found!
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally, this is working:

```
<?php $image_url = str_replace(' ', '%20', $row->photo);
if (file_exists('assets/images/upload/' . $image_url)) { ?>
    <td width="50" margin="0"><img src="assets/images/upload/{{$image_url}}" width="50"/></td>
<?php } else { ?>
    <td></td>
<?php } ?>
```